# Can the QuickOSM QGIS plugin be used with Overpass QL (rather than xml)?

Tags: qgis, overpass-api, quickosm

The QuickOSM plugin for QGIS can support users with the generation of new Overpass queries (for beginners on Overpass like me). It does this using the xml query language. I'd like to also be able to use this plugin with the alternative Overpass QL format. So far I've failed to do this despite having working queries on Overpass-turbo.

Can the plugin support the alternate language. Could I see a couple of queries - written for the plugin specifically - which work so I can base new queries on this?

The main reason for asking is that the answers I've been getting as I learn to use Overpass tend to be in Overpass QL.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, QuickOSM can execute an OQL query.

Even if QuickOSM generates XML and the OQL is not colored, QuickOSM forwards the query to Overpass so it should work.

I tried to run the query from the other post:

```
[out:json][timeout:90];
rel["route"="bicycle"](51.4177274438, 0.259382751254,51.553418261,0.0539556851102);
way(r);
way._["surface"="paved"];
out geom;
```

I got the error :

> The order must be node-way-relation. Check the print statement.

For your information, in your query, you are using:

> [out:json]

OGR can't read JSON, so QuickOSM will change on-the-fly to

> [out:xml]

Most of the time, it doesn't matter. But in the XML format, you should notice 3 categories : node, way and relation. Only nodes contain geographic informations. So ways relies on nodes. Relations relies on ways and nodes.
In the JSON format, the way has its own geometry.

To fix your problem, you can't request only ways in your query. You need to add a recurse down statement to fetch nodes which are part of ways:

```
[out:json][timeout:90];
rel["route"="bicycle"](51.4177274438, 0.259382751254,51.553418261,0.0539556851102);
way(r);
way._["surface"="paved"];
(._;>;);
out geom;
```

Comment: I haven't managed to make any query in OQL work (from the plugin). I may well be doing something really stupid - but without having even a single working example to start from I'm stuck. If you could give me even one very simple example which does work I can then through trial and error work towards what I need. For example the queries here don't work: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151108/an-overpass-query-for-osm-ways-both-part-of-a-relation-and-also-a-specific-tag

Comment: @Rostranimin I've updated my answer. Next time, share with us what kind of error you have. It's useful ;-)

Comment: I followed your suggestion taking the QL built by the wizard for `amenity=bench`.  In the plugin, I constantly get `Successful query, but no result.` which is not true because I can get data when I click on the Overpass turbo icon.

Comment: @AndreJ Do you use the same extent ? Use the button `Generate query` in QuickOSM to fix the bbox and then copy/paste the query in overpass turbo.

Comment: Yes the same extent. Switching to Overpass turbo takes the extent to the website.

Comment: Can you give me your query and bbox ?

Comment: See the example in my answer.

Comment: I have this working (thank you). And by changing the bounding box specified - the text (51.41.... ,... ,... , ....) -  to ({{bbox}}) it queries the area within the map canvas.

Comment: Actually - on closer inspection I'm getting odd results with this. If I run the query on Overpass-Turbo I get different results from using the plugin. For example, in Edinburgh the Overpass-Turbo site returns this way: http://www.openstreetmap.org/way/230759974 but the plugin doesn't.

Comment: @Rostranimin Sorry, with version 1.3.4 I can't replicate the issue. This way is downloaded with your query.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the Overpass Turbo Wizzard output for `amenity=bench` on an extent of 6.50876 to 6.56241 East and 51.3721 to 51.3915 North:

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“amenity=bench”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=bench”
  node["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

which results in

`Successful query, but no result.`

Running `Generate query` results in:

```
“amenity=bench”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “amenity=bench”
  node["amenity"="bench"](51.3720747317,6.50876494726,51.3915180471,6.50876494726);
  way["amenity"="bench"](51.3720747317,6.50876494726,51.3915180471,6.50876494726);
  relation["amenity"="bench"](51.3720747317,6.50876494726,51.3915180471,6.50876494726);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

which the plugin does not like at all: `Bad request OverpassAPI`

Quick Query in the plugin with `amenity=bench` returns values, as well as going back to Overpass Turbo via the icon in the plugin.

So I think it is **NOT** working (at least not in an easy way) with the current plugin version 1.3.4.

Comment: First you get `Bad request overpass API` because of your first comment `/* */` is not well structured. You forgot the beginning, the query works if you add `/*`. Secondly, even on Overpass turbo running the query I got no result : http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/akh So it's a problem between the extent and the bbox, not the plugin.

Comment: I also find a problem with this - and don't know what mistake I'm making. So for example [out:json][timeout:25];(node["amenity"="bench"]({{bbox}}););out geom; returns nothing from within the plugin but works fine on overpass turbo..

Comment: The plugin seems to substitute the bbox wrongly: minE, minN and maxN are correct, but maxE is set to minE, resulting in a line bbox which has obviously no content. Manually changing that value returns correct data. Just another bug ... I added the right bbox according to the Openstreetmap importer in my answer. Maybe this issue: https://github.com/3liz/QgisQuickOSMPlugin/issues/38

Comment: @AndreJ Sorry, I forgot that I was using the development version, not 1.3.4. So we can't compare our results. The good news, this seems to be fixed for the next release ;-) Create a ticket for every bug you've found. The next release will have a huge refactoring of the code.

Comment: So sounds like some of my issues were bug related? (Only some due to my ignorance). Look forward to the new version - this is such a useful plugin - I'm very keen to get it working well for me.

Comment: This bug should be fixed in the latest release 1.4.3.